# If a checkbox is checked or unchecked - code optimization - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So I have a jquery "checkbox checked/unchecked" function working well. This is a checkbox for turning on or off a particular URL parameter - BUT I believe this code could be written a lot tighter. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
$('#mapControl').live('click', function(){ 
    var thisUrl = $(location).attr('href');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var lastFour = thisUrl.substr(thisUrl.length - 4);
        var param;
        if (lastFour == 'com/') {param='?mapControl=true'} else {param='&mapControl=true'}
        thisUrl=thisUrl+param;
    } else {
        $('#urlParam').val(thisUrl);
        if (thisUrl.indexOf('?mapControl=true') >= 0){
            thisUrl=thisUrl.replace('?mapControl=true',''); 
        } else if (thisUrl.indexOf('&mapControl=true') >= 0){
            thisUrl=thisUrl.replace('&mapControl=true',''); 
        } 
    }
    $('#urlParam').val(thisUrl);
});
```

Comment: Post this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Start by not using the live() method (unless you are using a very old version of jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid jQuery as much as you can for example

```
$('#mapControl').live('click', function(){ 
// you can directly read window  location href attribute
var thisUrl = window.location.href;
var urlParamObj = $('#urlParam');
// instead of $(this).is(':checked') YOU can write *this.checked === true*
if(this.checked === true) {
    var lastFour = thisUrl.substr(thisUrl.length - 4);
    var param;
    if (lastFour == 'com/') {param='?mapControl=true'} else {param='&mapControl=true'}
    thisUrl=thisUrl+param;
} else {
    urlParamObj.val(thisUrl);
    /* if you are sure that your location may have "?mapControl=true" OR "&mapControl=true"you don't have to write code to check string directly replace   
    */
        thisUrl=thisUrl.replace('?mapControl=true',''); 
        thisUrl=thisUrl.replace('&mapControl=true',''); 
}
// you don't have to write $('#urlParam') 2 times create a object and refer it again and again
urlParamObj.val(thisUrl);
});
```